# How to calculate propagation delay of a combinational circuit?

Tags: verilog

I have googled this question, but i can't seem to find a proper answer. Is there a certain equation to it? Or do i calculate the delay by looking at the longest path in the circuit?

Comment: You don't calculate propagation delay for Verilog code, since this is high level code, and the propagation delay is only relevant for the resulting gate level implementation after place and route.  For this gate level implementation you use a Static Timing Analysis (STA) tool for propagation delay calculation based on constrains, whereby both minimum, maximum, clock delay, and lots of other timing considerations are included.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate path delays using static timing analysis tools that are usually provided by the target technology vendor (i.e. FPGA)

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty method - Open the synthesis report, and look for maximum combinational delay. This should give you an approximate value.

The right way - If the block is purely combinational, register the inputs and outputs using a clock of ANY frequency. Generate timing from input register to output register post implementation (place and route) using the tcl command report_timing -from {Flop1} -to {Flop2}. This will give you an elaborate description of cell and wire delays. This analysis would be accurate.